# MVC. HttpPostedFileBase is always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need some help. I'm trying to upload files using `<input type="file">`. Here is my View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("BookAdd", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="files[0]" id="files[0]" />
    <input type="file" name="files[1]" id="files[1]" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Book" />
}
```

And here is an Action which should process uploaded file.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BookAdd(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    // some actions
    return View();
}
```

The problem is that "files" always contains two elements which are null.
What can be done to fix it?

It's time for some news. It seems like I found the problem, but I still don't know how to fix it. It appears that despite the fact I'm using "multipart/form-data" here:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("BookAdd", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="File" id="file1" />
    <input type="file" name="File" id="file2" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Book" />
}
```

`Request.ContentType` remains "application/x-www-forum-urlencoded" in controller..

Comment: Don't worry, your English is perfect and your question is more than crystal clear.

Comment: you should really consider using a plugin. makes life easier, not to mention dealing with multiple browsers/runtimes. We use plupload. Works great.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just get rid of the square brackets in the names of your input fields:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("BookAdd", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" />
    <input type="file" name="files" id="file2" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Book" />
}
```

---

UPDATE:

After looking at the sample project you sent me the problem is that you have 2 nested forms. This is not allowed in HTML. You have one form in your `_Layout.cshtml` and another form in your `BookAdd.cshtml` view. That's the reason why despite the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute on your inner form you were getting the wrong `Request.ContentType`. So you will have to unnest those forms if you want this to work. Also in the example you sent me your `BookAdd` controller action doesn't have the correct signature taking a list of files, but I guess that's due to some tests you were doing.

Comment: ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods ("."). Reference http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#case

Comment: I tried to do this, but it resulted in following: now I receive empty IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> in controller (meaning Count = 0).

Comment: @Farrel, then you must be doing something different than what you have shown here. I have tested the code and it worked fine. The controller you are posting to must have the following signature: `public ActionResult BookAdd(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)`.

Comment: Actually the problem if already found. See my first message, it's updated. (Problem with Request.ContentType)

Comment: @Farrel, does the form have the `enctype` attribute when you look at the generated HTML source in the browser?

Comment: Do you mean the view itself? (the one containing <input type="file" ...>) If it is so, then no.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you meant. The page containing input hasn't enctype in it's HTML.

Comment: @Farrel, are you sure that you are using the correct signature of the `Html.BeginForm` method? There are many overloads. Be careful not to confuse between the `routeValues` and `htmlAttributes` argument. The one shown in the answer is correct.

Comment: Code looks exactly as you recommended to write.`@using (Html.BeginForm("BookAdd", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
//some inputs}`. You think it can be interprated in wrong way?

Comment: @Farrel, could you send me your sample project by mail so that I can see what's wrong with it?

Comment: Yes, of couse. but there is one more problem. I don't know how, but I didnt noiticed that enctype actually presents in HTML. I guess it changes the situation.

Comment: @Farrel, I am afraid that from the information present here I cannot help you further since I cannot reproduce the problem. As I said it works for me. So there's probably something else going on in your project.

Comment: Ok, I'll send progect as fast as I can.

Comment: @Farrel, I got your project. The problem is that you have 2 nested forms. This is not allowed in HTML. You have one form in your `_Layout.cshtml` and another form in your `BookAdd.cshtml` view. That's the reason why despite the `enctype="multipatr/form-data"` attribute on your inner form you were getting the wrong Request.ContentType. So you will have to unnest those forms if you want this to work. Also in the example you sent me your BookAdd controller action doesn't have the correct signature taking a list of files, but I guess that's due to some tests you were doing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Darin. You're right and now everything works fine.

Comment: Thanks for saving my time. yes there was form inside form.

Answer (score 37):

The problem is that the NAME of the field need to match with the controller parameter.
In your case is "files"... so your `name` attribute should be "files" also.

Comment: The parameter was always null for me when doing an <input type="file" multiple /> until the name attribute matched the function parameter name...

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it for me, but now I have a new problem. Is there away to pass  an id or attribute from the view that I can recognize and determine which file is which in the controller?

Comment: @Mans, You can pass a ViewModel as an additional parameter with any field, besides de IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> param (or only a ViewModel with the HttpPostedFileBase inside).  If you need to identify what file is what, you could add several file inputs, and that way you know which is which.

Answer (score 7):

I was facing same problem but in my case i got a solution of this.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload()
    {
        foreach (string file in Request.Files)
        {               
           fileurl = Request.Files[file];
        }
        return View();
    }
```

**In Design View.Please Comment out Form Tag `<%-- <form id="form1" runat="server">--%>` if using Master Page...I hope Your problem will be solve...**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Upload
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

   <%-- <form id="form1" runat="server">--%>
  <% using (Html.BeginForm("Upload","Home",FormMethod.Post,new {enctype="multipart/form-data"}))
{ %>

<fieldset>
        <legend>Upload File</legend>
         <div>

          <p>
Select a File: <input type="file" name="FileUpload" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</p>
</div>
</fieldset>

<% } %>
```

Answer (score 4):

Worth noting if you're using AJAX then the upload will always come through as null, so make sure no jquery AJAX is attached to the form submit.

Answer (score 2):

You must write some like this:

```
public class DocumentModelView 
{
        public HttpPostedFileBase File1 { get; set; }

        public HttpPostedFileBase File2 { get; set; }
}


@model Models.DocumentModelView

@using( Html.BeginForm( "Create", "Document", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }) )
{
        <input type="file" name="File1" />
    <input type="file" name="File2" />
        <input type="submit" value="send" />
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create( DocumentModelView modelView )
{
.....
}
```

Comment: But he wants to upload multiple files, not one.

Comment: Well, it still refuses to work. The only one thing I can think of is the variable name in controller. As I understood it can be any name (according to your example). Both File1 and File2 are null.

Comment: Yes, DocumentModelView is only a object (I have get it from an exist project) that contains file informations.

Comment: Actually I meant "modelView" by saying name.

Answer (score 1):

In my case y had to use the name instead of id.

Like this:

```
<input type="file" id="upload" name="upload" />
```