# Upload files by Ajax.BeginForm in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

How could I upload files or images to the server by these means:

I would like using `Ajax.BeginForm()` for handling users profiles.

It would give the mechanism for processing `Json` responses from server and update message containers information.

Answer (score 2):

You can't upload a file using Ajax.BeginForm

You can use JQuery Plugins or Uploadify

http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: How can I achieve this as you speak. Please, reference any example with these techniques.

Comment: @Félix, check this example for uploadify

Comment: @Félix, here is sample code for JQuery. It's fairly elegant. http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: check this question, I do this with jquery form plugin. If you want to use it, I will give you an example with multiple uploads. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842842/asp-net-mvc-ajax-file-upload-with-jquery-form-plugin