# HttpPostedFileBase returns null after submitting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I keep on getting null with HttpPosterFileBase when I try uploading a file:

I have this code in my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Import", "Control", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="fileUpload"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Import" id="btnImport" class="button" />
}
```

And this code with my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Import()
{    
     HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileUpload];            
     Other codes...
}
```

I also tried this in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Import(HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload)
{        
    Other codes...
}
```

After pressing the submit button the "file" got a value of null.

Comment: Do you see file in post data?

Comment: any ajax involved in this?

Answer (score 1):

The default model binder binds by name for files. Your inputs name is `fileUpload`.. your parameter name is `file`. Making them the same will work.

Comment: Hi,thanks but I already match the parameter and input name and still no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing your binding correctly, change this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Import(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{        
    // other stuff
}
```

To:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Import(HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload)
{        
    // other stuff
}
```

Comment: Hi,thanks but upon doing this, I still got no luck. still null value :(

Answer (score 0):

Your names can't match because this code below works for me, unless you use some kind of jQuery or Ajax that's preventing this to work you should be good. It's the name of the file upload input and the `HttpPostedFileBase` name that must match.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("import", "control", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="fileupload" />
    <input type="submit" value="Import" id="btnImport" class="button" />
}



[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Import(HttpPostedFileBase fileupload)
{
      return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your answers. I believe all those answers are correct but I was able to fix the problem after I notice that I have nested forms with page. Found the solution after reading the answer here: [MVC. HttpPostedFileBase is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159725/mvc-httppostedfilebase-is-always-null)

Again, Thanks! Cheers! :)